# Make OData service work in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, odata

I have a sample from MS for an OData service. here's the pertinent code:

```
        using (WebApp.Start(_baseAddress, Configuration))
        {...}
```

and

```
    public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder builder)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "OData", routePrefix: "odata", model: GetModel());
        builder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

with

```
    private static IEdmModel GetModel()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

This works perfectly and the Products controller is great. I'm now trying to move it over to a web project to work in IIS but I'm getting a blank document returned. I've managed to trace it to the line

```
builder.UseWebApi(config);
```

Or at least when I comment this line out it gives the same behaviour. The sample is from https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataOpenTypeSample/ as I'm trying to use DynamicProperties on my return objects.

Here's the code for my IIS project WebApiConfig:

```
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "OData", routePrefix: "odata", model: GetModel());
        }

        private static IEdmModel GetModel()
        {
            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
            var edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
            return edmModel;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataActionsSample/ is on IIS host, you may want to compare your project with it. And I don't think config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); is needed.